# Displaying PDFs inline in Umbraco

Tags: pdf, media, inline, umbraco

Folks,
I've got badly stuck with something that I thought would be easy: I have a page and I want to display a PDF that's stored in my media collection.

I can link to a PDF using the standard toolbar but to embed a PDF, I have to turn to xslt and macro code.

This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:Stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
 version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="pdfFile" select="$currentPage/data [@alias='pdfFile']"/>

 <xsl:if test="$pdfFile!= '' ">
   <embed width="796" height="1032"> 
     <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(./data [@alias = 'pdfFile'], 'false')/data [@alias = 'umbracoFile']"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
   </embed>
 </xsl:if>

 </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it's not working - I get nothing on the page. I've looked for solutions to this (perhaps my reference to GetMedia is wrong) but I can't find anything that'll help me.
Oh, my macro is using pdfFile as the parameter and is set as mediaCurrent.
I'm using Umbraco 4.7.1

Any pointers, help or advice would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the resulting HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's pretty easy.
Here it is documented for anyone using Umbraco 4.7.x and who needs to display pdf files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:Stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp " "> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
        version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:param name="pdf" select="/macro/pdfFile"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <embed width="100%" height="500"> 
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pdf/File/umbracoFile"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </embed>
  </xsl:template>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For clarification, you will also need a macro (name unimportant) that uses this xslt. You will also have to add a parameter to the macro called *pdfFile*, click on the 'show' checkbox and then save it all.
The width and height of the *embed* can, of course, be set to whatever suits you.
Have fun.